# Using ffmpeg to overlay dvdsub subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I am trying to overlay a dvdsub file pair (*.idx + *.sub) to a video file.

[Here is the sub pair.](http://www.filedropper.com/mysub)

This is the batch script with the command line I am trying to use:

```
@echo off
set srcVidFile1="myvideo.mov"
set srcSubFile=mysub.sub
set srcIdxFile=mysub.idx
set destFile=D:\testsub.mp4

ffmpeg.exe -i %srcVidFile1% -i %srcSubFile% -i %srcIdxFile% 
    -filter_complex "[0:v][1:s]overlay" -c:s dvdsub -c:v 
    libx264 -crf 24 -c:a aac -b:a 160K -ar 48K -strict -2 -y 
    %destFile%
```

This however only accepts 720x576 VOBsub files. And also the color gets inverted.

My video however is 1080p and do have a 1920x1080 VOBsub file pair, but when I trying use them, I get an error **sub2video: rectange (xxx xxx xxx xxx) overflowing 720 576**

Looks like adding `-canvas_size 1920x1080` before `-i %srcSubFile%` handles the error on the canvas size. But I can't figure out the color.

The full output:

```
    ffmpeg version N-81516-gbe07c25 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
      libavcodec     57. 54.101 / 57. 54.101
      libavformat    57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
      libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
      libavfilter     6. 58.100 /  6. 58.100
      libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
      libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'myvideo.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2017-07-18T19:00:46.000000Z
        timecode        : 00:59:58;00
      Duration: 00:01:19.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 146880 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 145344 kb/s, 29.97 fps,
29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 29970 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-07-18T19:00:46.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Avid DNxHD Codec
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-07-18T19:00:46.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-07-18T19:01:18.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          timecode        : 00:59:58;00
    Input #1, mpeg, from 'mysub.sub':
      Duration: 00:00:52.88, start: 3600.042000, bitrate: 10 kb/s
        Stream #1:0[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Input #2, vobsub, from 'mysub.idx':
      Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #2:0[0x0](en): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 1920x1080 (default)
    [mpeg @ 0000000002de4580] sub2video: using 720x576 canvas
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] profile High, level 4.0
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] 264 - core 148 r2705 3f5ed56 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=24.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [mp4 @ 00000000005218a0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
        Last message repeated 2 times
    Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\testsub.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        timecode        : 00:59:58;00
        encoder         : Lavf57.48.101
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 0.03 fps, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.54.101 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, padding 0, 160 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-07-18T19:00:46.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Lavc57.54.101 aac
        Stream #0:2: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle (dvdsub) ([224][0][0][0] / 0x00E0), 720x480
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.54.101 dvdsub
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 (dnxhd) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
      Stream #1:0 (dvdsub) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
      overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
      Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (dvd_subtitle (dvdsub) -> dvd_subtitle (dvdsub))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    sub2video: rectangle (942 858 163 60) overflowing 720 576
        Last message repeated 1 times
    frame=   33 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=14.1x    
    frame=   63 fps= 62 q=30.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=  11.1kbits/s speed=7.01x    
    frame=   91 fps= 59 q=30.0 size=      30kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=  34.7kbits/s speed= 4.6x    
    frame=  112 fps= 55 q=30.0 size=     197kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate= 227.9kbits/s speed=3.45x    
    frame=  124 fps= 47 q=30.0 size=     407kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate= 470.6kbits/s speed=2.69x    
    frame=  137 fps= 44 q=30.0 size=     639kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate= 738.6kbits/s speed=2.26x    
    frame=  152 fps= 41 q=30.0 size=     861kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate= 995.4kbits/s speed=1.89x    
    frame=  163 fps= 37 q=30.0 size=    1002kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=1158.6kbits/s speed=1.63x    
    frame=  175 fps= 36 q=30.0 size=    1412kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=1633.3kbits/s speed=1.46x    
    frame=  187 fps= 35 q=30.0 size=    1642kB time=00:00:07.31 bitrate=1838.4kbits/s speed=1.36x    
    frame=  202 fps= 34 q=30.0 size=    1892kB time=00:00:07.82 bitrate=1979.7kbits/s speed=1.31x    
    frame=  213 fps= 33 q=30.0 size=    2071kB time=00:00:08.19 bitrate=2071.2kbits/s speed=1.26x    
    sub2video: rectangle (419 785 1209 133) overflowing 720 576
    frame=  225 fps= 32 q=30.0 size=    2363kB time=00:00:09.54 bitrate=2028.5kbits/s speed=1.36x    
    frame=  236 fps= 31 q=30.0 size=    2554kB time=00:00:09.54 bitrate=2192.6kbits/s speed=1.26x    
    frame=  249 fps= 31 q=30.0 size=    2760kB time=00:00:09.54 bitrate=2369.7kbits/s speed=1.18x    
    frame=  262 fps= 30 q=30.0 size=    2957kB time=00:00:09.83 bitrate=2463.4kbits/s speed=1.14x    
    frame=  272 fps= 29 q=30.0 size=    3111kB time=00:00:10.15 bitrate=2509.4kbits/s speed=1.09x    
    frame=  283 fps= 29 q=30.0 size=    3796kB time=00:00:10.51 bitrate=2957.1kbits/s speed=1.07x    
    sub2video: rectangle (942 858 163 60) overflowing 720 576
    frame=  289 fps= 28 q=30.0 size=    4144kB time=00:00:13.62 bitrate=2491.4kbits/s speed=1.32x    
    frame=  297 fps= 27 q=30.0 size=    4613kB time=00:00:13.62 bitrate=2773.6kbits/s speed=1.26x    
    frame=  304 fps= 27 q=30.0 size=    5036kB time=00:00:13.62 

    [---TRUNCATED REST OF FRAMES---]

    video:94601kB audio:1616kB subtitle:52kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.085206%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] frame I:35    Avg QP:23.92  size:153135
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] frame P:958   Avg QP:26.88  size: 69163
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] frame B:1375  Avg QP:26.60  size: 18365
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] consecutive B-frames: 22.2%  0.7%  1.3% 75.8%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] mb I  I16..4: 11.8% 84.0%  4.2%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] mb P  I16..4:  3.2% 22.6%  0.4%  P16..4: 40.9% 10.7%  6.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:15.4%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  2.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 44.9%  2.2%  0.4%  direct: 2.8%  skip:47.2%  L0:45.9% L1:51.3% BI: 2.8%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] 8x8 transform intra:86.2% inter:89.3%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 76.4% 65.9% 37.2% inter: 23.4% 29.3% 3.5%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 42%  5% 34%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10%  9% 47%  5%  6%  5%  6%  5%  6%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 18% 17%  7% 11%  9% 10%  6%  7%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 63% 16% 16%  5%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.2% UV:2.9%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] ref P L0: 50.5% 14.8% 22.5% 11.6%  0.6%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] ref B L0: 87.9%  9.7%  2.4%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] ref B L1: 95.2%  4.8%
    [libx264 @ 00000000005234c0] kb/s:9808.13
    [aac @ 0000000000524340] Qavg: 574.088
```

Original subtitle:
[image: Subtitle image]

Rendered frame:
[image: Rendered frame]

I would like to input the 1920x1080 VOBsub file pair and overlay it on the 1080p video with 24bit original colors.

Can somebody give me the correct command line for this?

And as it seems that the VOBsub are low res, is there any means that allow overlaying 1920x1080 24 bit pngs using ffmpeg?

Comment: Share full log for your command.

Comment: Share a screenshot showing the color as rendered, and ideally, one with the desired colors.

Comment: @ib11 "...the ssa format has limitations." What are the limitations? Can you provide the sub and idx files?

Comment: I meant the limitations is: border and drop shadow. You can't diffuse the drop shadow and I know of no ways to increase caracter or line spacing. I have been using photoshoped png files placed on top of the track in Avid to get the exact look.

Comment: @llogan I created the sub files from hi-res pngs using SubtitleEdit-3.5.9 and the sub file contains I think 8-bit bitmaps, at least based on the rendered frame it looks like (just as a DVD would have). So far I have found no was rendering 24-bit HD subtitles other than cutting them in with avid. Using the ssa format is the only alternative, but as above, I did not find a way to modify  character spacing and diffusion of the drop shadow.

Comment: Provide the sub files if you can.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is old. [Update](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) it, and use the idx file as the overlay input instead of the sub file.

Comment: @llogan Thanks. Do I just swap the two `-i %srcSubFile% -i %srcIdxFile%`? Also any suggestion how to put 24-bit pngs in the sub file?

Comment: You can just swap if you prefer, but you only need `-i %srcIdxFile%`, so you can eliminate `-i %srcSubFile%`. Sorry, but I don't know anything about SubtitleEdit.

Comment: @llogan Thanks. Okay, I am installing and update to try your suggestion. As to SubtitleEdit -- me neither. Is there any way you know to embed 24-bit pngs using ffmpeg? If I could make a sub & idx file pair that would work, but they seem to bee only 8-bit pix.

Comment: @llogan I tried to run the following command with the latest build (64-bit) of ffmpeg and it is very slow (150x), any idea? `ffmpeg.exe -i %srcVidFile1% -canvas_size 1920x1080 -i %srcIdxFile% -filter_complex "[0:v][1:s]overlay" -c:s dvdsub -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -c:a aac -b:a 160K -ar 48K -strict -2 -y %destFile%`

Comment: @ib11 Need to see the log.

Comment: @llogan Here is the log: http://www.filedropper.com/log_1